# Get child categories of custom taxonomy category?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am using custom `post type : portfolio` and have taxonomy for that `portfolio_category`. I need to get sub categories for a particular category using the above custom taxonomy.

In short, How can I get the child categories for `taxonomy=portfolio_category&tag_ID=80&post_type=portfolio`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

```
$categories = get_terms('portfolio_category', 'parent=80');
```

And obviously change **80** to be the ID of the category you want to get the children of.

Also note this from the codex:

```
Note: the difference between child_of and parent is that where parent only gets direct children of the parent term (ie: 1 level down), child_of gets all descendants (as many levels as are available)
```

So **parent=80** is going to get the direct children of that category, but if one of those child categories has a child of it's own, and you wanted that to be included, you will want to use **child_of=80**.